# Adding three indicators in one script

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to add DMI, RSI and RVI in one script. But encountering the following message -
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 16: 'len' is already defined.
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 22: 'len' is already defined.

My code is as follows -

```
    //@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source")
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
//@version=5
indicator(title="Directional Movement Index", shorttitle="DMI", format=format.price, precision=4, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
lensig = input.int(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")
up = ta.change(high)
down = -ta.change(low)
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
trur = ta.rma(ta.tr, len)
plus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(plusDM, len) / trur)
minus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(minusDM, len) / trur)
sum = plus + minus
adx = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)
plot(adx, color=#F50057, title="ADX")
plot(plus, color=#2962FF, title="+DI")
plot(minus, color=#FF6D00, title="-DI")
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Volatility Index", shorttitle="RVI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(10, minval=1), src = close
len = 14
stddev = ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = ta.ema(ta.change(src) <= 0 ? 0 : stddev, len)
lower = ta.ema(ta.change(src) > 0 ? 0 : stddev, len)
rvi = upper / (upper + lower) * 100
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot(rvi, title="RVI", color=#7E57C2, offset = offset)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you are trying to combine two indicator you have to keep in mind that the variable names must be unique. Here in your case source and length has been defined more than once so I have renamed it accordingly (make sure two variables with same name are no there in the code.

I have provided the code without any error below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length",group="RSI setting")
src = input(close, "Source",group="RSI setting")
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")


lensig_adx = input.int(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50,group="ADX setting")
len_adx = input.int(14, minval=1, title="DI Length",group="ADX setting")
up_adx = ta.change(high)
down_adx = -ta.change(low)
plusDM_adx = na(up_adx) ? na : (up_adx > down_adx and up_adx > 0 ? up_adx : 0)
minusDM_adx = na(down_adx) ? na : (down_adx > up_adx and down_adx > 0 ? down_adx : 0)
trur_adx = ta.rma(ta.tr, len_adx)
plus_adx = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(plusDM_adx, len_adx) / trur_adx)
minus_adx = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(minusDM_adx, len_adx) / trur_adx)
sum_adx = plus_adx + minus_adx
adx_adx = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plus_adx - minus_adx) / (sum_adx == 0 ? 1 : sum_adx), lensig_adx)
plot(adx_adx, color=#F50057, title="ADX")
plot(plus_adx, color=#2962FF, title="+DI")
plot(minus_adx, color=#FF6D00, title="-DI")


length_rvi = input.int(10, minval=1,group="RVI setting")
src_rvi = close
len_rvi = 14
stddev_rvi = ta.stdev(src_rvi, length_rvi)
upper_rvi = ta.ema(ta.change(src_rvi) <= 0 ? 0 : stddev_rvi, len_rvi)
lower_rvi = ta.ema(ta.change(src_rvi) > 0 ? 0 : stddev_rvi, len_rvi)
rvi_rvi = upper_rvi / (upper_rvi + lower_rvi) * 100
h0_rvi = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h1_rvi = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0_rvi, h1_rvi, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot(rvi_rvi, title="RVI", color=#7E57C2, offset = offset)
```

Comment: You are my savior. Is it possible to have this indicators in different panes? Thanks again, along with my humble gratitude. Regards.

Comment: one indicator means one pane, If you want it in different pane then you have to add all three indicators separately

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In Pine script, if you are going to change a value of an existing variable you need to type

```
:=
```

So the first time you create your variable you type "=" and the second time you type ":=", when you assign it a new value

example:

```
len = 10
len := 30
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I made the changes, but now it is giving me the following error -  "Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 7: Syntax error at input '('." 

The Line 7 is as follows - "(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)". 

Help me to resolve the issue. Thanks & regards.

Comment: I think you have to create a new Stackoverflow question, for that new error.